# How to align buttom TextField by top TextField?

Tags: flutter

I need to align bottom input field by top input field. Like:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
class CustomerInput extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
          //   ),
        ),
          TextField(
            enabled: false,
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why not use the `decoration` property of `Textfield`? You can pass an `InputDecorator` which contains the magnifier icon

Comment: I need button that can be pressed.

Comment: Well, it accepts a widget, so you can build an IconButton there and pass logic to its `onPressed` property

Comment: @Julien Lachal is it's possible to put this icon to right side, by default it in left

Comment: Yes, the `InputDecoration` has a `suffixIcon` property, it's the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

in this code **flex** property of **TextField** is **3** and **RaisedButton** is **1**

**"sum equality of these is 4"**

> **TextField** will expand by **3/4** or **75%** and **RaisedButton**  by **1/4** or **25%**

by this concept i created new **Row** and putted in it

- **TextField** its **flex** is equal to **top one**  .
- **Container** its **flex** is equal to **Raisedbutton's flex** .

and the edited code is :

```
      `

      Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
          //   ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: TextField(
                enabled: false,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give exact view as you need. In second raw you will add only one TextFormField/TextField for edittext/textview.

```
     Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: TextFormField(

                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              //   ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
```